# Writing a int to hex converter that only takes Int as an Input

Tags: c#

```
namespace HexConverter
{
    class HexConverter
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I/O Hex Converter");
            GetUserInput();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        private static void GetUserInput()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Int value: ");

            int userInput = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("{0} Converted to Hex is: {0:X}", userInput);
        }
    }
}
```

I’ve been trying to figure out how to add a loop to control the input the ReadLine accepts as only an integer value to be converted. I used an if/else to convert the input using a TryParse else prompt the user to only input an Int value. Then I came up with a do/while loop to try and keep it asking for input until an Int was added but it wouldn’t convert the userInput to hex. So I’m back at square one, and I’m still stumped. How would I keep it from throwing an exception if anything other than Int was input, while also continuously asking until that condition was met?

Comment: What do you men by _" it wouldn’t convert the userInput to hex"_ ? some example input & output may help us help you. Maybe show your attempts with TryParse.

Comment: `Int32.TryParse()`

Comment: Used if(!int.TryParse(userInput , out num) else Console.WriteLine(“Only enter an Int value: “) entering “ok” or a single character prompted for another entry. But entering 8888 for example would not return its hex equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This produces the behavior as described when run on [a C# REPL](https://IO-Input-Loop-Example.quizlibet.repl.run)

```
using System;
namespace HexConverter
{
    class HexConverter
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I/O Hex Converter");
            GetUserInput();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        private static void GetUserInput()
        {
            string userInput;
            int candidateNum;
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter Int Value: ");
                userInput = Console.ReadLine();
            } while(!int.TryParse(userInput, out candidateNum));

            Console.WriteLine("{0} Converted to Hex is: {0:X}", candidateNum);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using your code Jawi, it returns the hex value. But if you entered “ok” for example or a single char it returns Time Limit Exceeded.

Comment: What is the desired behaviour once a valid integer is input? a perpetual input loop, or should there be a character that terminates the program

Comment: Perpetual loop until an integer is entered for conversion then program terminated upon output of hex equivalent.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was over thinking it trying to include an if else. I really appreciate your feedback.